# How to store Arabic characters on SQL DATABASE

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a website in which the user has to submit his name written in arabic, but in the database it looks something like "?????" , i made a search to solve the problem, i knew that i had to change the collation, but the problem is there no collation named "Arabic CI.... Etc" and there is no collation supports arabic... Also there is no nvarchar type... Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

use N before your text:

N'سلام'

Comment: it worked... Thnx very much, can u plz expain it? Why that happened

Comment: you're welcome. you can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: using N means that your text is Unicode. without it, some db don't realize some characters.

Comment: Thnx very much, that was so helpful